# How to change the background color of the parent?

Tags: javascript, colors, element, parent, onload

I'm trying to change the background color of a parent element, using onload.

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/gredesign/pen/GmXmPX?editors=1100

```
<div id="parent">
  <span onload="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='grey';">Test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do it in the body tag. But it's better not to use inline scripts. Add an event handler instead.

Answer (score 1):

hello you can do it with jquery 
you listenon the loader id and set the background when the loader reach state ready on dom

```js
    $( "#loader").ready(function() {
      $(this).parent().css({backgroundColor: 'red'});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
      <span id="loader" >Test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ottmar, I was able to use what you provided to find the exact answer I was looking for. The solution I was searching for was more of a pure javascript solution, that wouldn't involve external libraries. I should have been more specific on that. To see what I ended up with, see the answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue here might be adding `onload` instead of breaking it into a js/jquery function. Unless you have a specific need to write it inline, you can simply add an ID or class and reference it in a separate function. This has the added benefit of being able to debug it much more easily.

`parentNode` is just fine and I see no need to load jquery for a single function that javascript already has under a different name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I was looking for below. Thanks for everyone's help and insight.

https://codepen.io/gredesign/pen/JNarGX?editors=1111

```
<div id="parent">
<span value="red">123456</span>
</div>
<script> 
  var color = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].attributes[0].value; 
  document.getElementById("parent").style.backgroundColor=color;
</script>
```